# Proof of Zariski Topology theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I kinda lost there when I'm making a title so I'm just gonna ask forward. I'm having a difficulties when proving that $$ V(\varphi^{-1}(I)) \subseteq \overline{\psi(V(I))}$$ given that $\psi : Spec(B) \rightarrow Spec(A)$ and $\varphi : A \rightarrow B$, $A, B$ ring with identity and $\varphi$ homomorphism. Can someone help me working on this?

Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 0):

For any prime ideal $P$ of $A$ which contains $\varphi^{-1}(I)$, you want to show that 
$$\bigcap_{\substack{Q\in\mathrm{Spec}(B)\\ I\subseteq Q}} \varphi^{-1}(Q) \subseteq P $$
Let $f\in A$ be such that $f$ is contained in the left hand side, i.e.  $\varphi(f)$ is contained in each $Q\in V(I)$. This means $\varphi(f)\in \bigcap_{Q\in V(I)} Q = \sqrt I$, so $\varphi(f^k)=\varphi(f)^k\in I$ for some $k$. But that means $f^k\in\varphi^{-1}(I)\subseteq P$ and $P$ was prime, so $f\in P$.